# Apply of a logic function over a list

Tags: functions, apply

I'm trying to apply a logic function over a list, but:

e.g.`(apply 'and some_list)` give me `Invalid function: and`.

There is a way to apply a logical function to a list?

Comment: `C-h f apply`.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `and` is not a function (it is a *special form*).

Note that `C-h f and` tells you "and is a special form in `C source code'."

`apply` must be used with a function.

The manual says:

> ```
> ‘apply’ returns the result of calling FUNCTION.  As with ‘funcall’,
>  FUNCTION must either be a Lisp function or a primitive function;
>  special forms and macros do not make sense in ‘apply’.
> ```

Comment: there is any `and` function in elisp?

Comment: It's not possible to write `and` as a function -- functions evaluate *all* of their arguments, whereas macros and special forms receive their arguments un-evaluated (which is necessary for `and`, which must not evaluate the remaining arguments if it has already failed).

Comment: there is a non lazy set of logic functions? or, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: @FrancescoCadei For `and` you have `(cl-every #'identity some_list)` and for `or` you have `(cl-some #'identity some_list)`.

Comment: If all you want is a nil or non-nil result, then `(memq nil LIST)` will tell you if any of the list elements is `nil`.